# UK citizen trading in USA?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, trading, brokerage

I am a UK citizen and have worked in the US in the past on work visa. I am back in the UK now but want to start investing in the US stock market. I have a valid SSN and a US back account. Are there any restrictions on me opening a US based brokerage account? If I can open such an account, what are my tax implications towards the US government?

Comment: Any reason why you want to open a US brokerage account and not a UK brokerage account, allowing you to trade in US markets ?

Comment: I may be back in the US soon for long term, if a few things work out.

Comment: @user39382 unless you're going to get a US Passport anytime soon, I'd highly advise DumbCoders' suggestion (Hardly as dumb as his name suggests!)